# To restart a service (e.g httpd), should I use /etc/init.d httpd restart or /sbin/service httpd restart?

Tags: linux, service

Whenever I need to restart Apache on my RHEL VPS, I type `sudo /sbin/service httpd restart`.  However I notice a lot of articles suggest using `sudo /etc/init.d httpd restart`.

Is there any difference?  If there is, when I should use each one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the man page:

> service  runs  a  System V init script in as predictable environment as possible, removing most environment variables and with current working directory set to /.

It then calls the `init.d` script.  So they both accomplish the same thing, except calling the script via `/sbin/service` just ensures that some environment variables in your shell don't screw up the `init.d` script.

Answer (score 7):

Using `/sbin/service` is good because it gives the daemon a fresh environment to work in, without any potentially-annoying environment variables getting in the way and causing havoc.  At least, that's the rationale for requiring it at work; I've always used the init scripts directly on my other-distro machines and it hasn't caused a visible problem, but I'm assured that there was a real problem that `/sbin/service` is working around.  Perhaps RHEL systems just have more crap laying around in the default environment.

Answer (score 4):

My advice would be to use whatever you want whenever you're actually logged in to the machine, and use `/etc/(init.d|rc.d)/daemon-name` if you are scripting, the reason being the latter is generally more portable. IIRC, the only distros that come with `/sbin/service` in the base packages install are RH-flavored, i.e. RHEL, CentOS, Fedora. My Debian systems for example do not have this script, however this may not matter for your environment.

Comment: Debian-based systems have 'invoke-rc.d' which fills the same roll as service.

Comment: There really should be a distribution-independent way of doing this.